# VBO Cubes not rendering -- Testing for unsupported features

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, opengl-3

I am trying to render a large cube composed of other cubes (`10x10x10 for a total of 1000 cubes). It works fine my computer and one of my friends' computer, but another one is just getting a blank screen. I am assuming it is because they do not have some supported function I am using. I want to know what function it is and how I can tell they do not have support for it so I can tell them.

EDIT: The problematic computer is doing everything BUT rendering the cubes. It gives a completely blank screen with the proper background color.

I have all this hidden in a class so, I am just giving the relevant parts.

If you need anymore info, just ask.

GL_VENDOR, GL_RENDER, GL_VERSION ann GL_EXTENSION of problem computer (copy and paste out to format better):

```
[01:28:02] GL_VENDOR: Intel
[01:28:02] GL_RENDERER: Intel(R) HD Graphics
[01:28:02] GL_VERSION: 2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2858
[01:28:02] GL_EXTENSIONS: GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_NV_blend_square GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_NV_conditional_render GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_array GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_INTEL_performance_queries GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
```

Code:

```
void Block::setColor(float r, float g, float b) {
this->m_colorBuffer.clear();

this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));
this->m_colorBuffer.push_back(Color(r, g, b));

    //Send the color data to OpenGL
if (m_colorvbo[0] != -1) glDeleteBuffers(1, m_colorvbo);
glGenBuffers(1, m_colorvbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_colorvbo[0]); //Bind the vertex buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * m_colorBuffer.size(), &m_colorBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL
}

bool Block::initialize()
{
    glGenBuffers(LAST_BUFFER, m_vbos); //Generate a buffer for the vertices, indices and colors

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    float size = 0.5f;
    //Push back 8 vertices that make up a cube
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex(-size, -size,  size));
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex(-size, -size, -size));
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex( size, -size, -size));
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex( size, -size,  size));

    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex(-size,  size,  size));
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex(-size,  size, -size));
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex( size,  size, -size));
    m_vertices.push_back(Vertex( size,  size,  size));

    //Push back the indices that make up the triangles for each face.
    m_indices.push_back(0);
    m_indices.push_back(2);
    m_indices.push_back(3);
    m_indices.push_back(0);
    m_indices.push_back(1);
    m_indices.push_back(2);

    m_indices.push_back(4);
    m_indices.push_back(6);
    m_indices.push_back(7);
    m_indices.push_back(4);
    m_indices.push_back(5);
    m_indices.push_back(6);

m_indices.push_back(0);
m_indices.push_back(4);
m_indices.push_back(1);
m_indices.push_back(4);
m_indices.push_back(5);
m_indices.push_back(1);

m_indices.push_back(2);
m_indices.push_back(6);
m_indices.push_back(3);
m_indices.push_back(6);
m_indices.push_back(7);
m_indices.push_back(3);

m_indices.push_back(6);
m_indices.push_back(1);
m_indices.push_back(5);
m_indices.push_back(6);
m_indices.push_back(2);
m_indices.push_back(1);

m_indices.push_back(0);
m_indices.push_back(7);
m_indices.push_back(4);
m_indices.push_back(0);
m_indices.push_back(3);
m_indices.push_back(7);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[VERTEX_BUFFER]); //Bind the vertex buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * m_vertices.size(), &m_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[INDEX_BUFFER]); //Bind the vertex buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * m_indices.size(), &m_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL

bufferInit = true;

    return true;
}

void Block::render()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    //Set the vertex pointer for the cube
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[INDEX_BUFFER]); //Bind the vertex buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_colorvbo[0]);
    glTranslatef(this->position.x, this->position.y, this->position.z);
    //glScalef(this->size, this->size, this->size);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Trye the OpenGL extension checker - http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/

Comment: How would this help any? Sorry if I do not understand, but this would just give me the GL Extensions I can get from the code right? Or does it tell me what functions can be used etc.? I am bed and cannot test it now, but will test tomorrow.

Comment: Well you know what extensions you use, and that utility will tell you which of thos extensions are supported on the non-working machine.

Comment: Do consider it might _not_ be related to extensions at all, it might be an OpenGL state you don't set explicitly that has a different default value there. Do you still have your non-VBO code? Try and see if _that_ works on the problem machine. Also, nitpicking a typo, 10x10x10 = 1000 ;-).

Comment: Typo fixed. Sorry :P Also, I have no idea what value it could be. I am going through and setting just about everything GL_DEPTH_TEST, GL_LEQUAL, disable GL_CULL_FACE. Could it have anything to do with that only have OpenGL 2.1 and mine having 3.0? I will try using non-VBO code on her computer once I see here. I kind of do not have access to it at the moment. I just sent her an exe and said run this. Haha